# Kotlin/Native: Can someone help me in suggesting how to create a frozen singleton that takes in init parameters?

Tags: ios, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

Below code will not work because companion object will be created and made immutable as soon as we try to access it like `SomeClass.getInstance()` or any other property of it and I won't be able to initialise `someClass` property. I want it to be immutable/frozen (because this will be accessed from multiple threads) but I can't do it when it takes parameters.

Any suggestions?

```
actual open class SomeClass private constructor(private val someProperty: SomeProperty) {
    actual companion object {
        private var someClass: SomeClass? = null
        fun initialize(someProperty: SomeProperty){
            someClass = SomeClass(someProperty)
        }
        actual fun getInstance(): SomeClass {
            if (someClass == null) {
                throw UninitializedPropertyAccessException("SomeClass is not initialised yet")
            }
            return someClass as SomeClass
        }
    }
}
```

One possible solution is to use AtomicReference here. Like so:

```
actual open class SomeClass private constructor(private val someProperty: SomeProperty) {
    actual companion object {
        private var someClassAtomicRef: AtomicReference<SomeClass?> = AtomicReference(null)
        fun initialize(someProperty: SomeProperty){
            val someClass = SomeClass(someProperty)
            someClassAtomicRef.value = someClass.freeze()
        }
        actual fun getInstance(): SomeClass {
            return someClassAtomicRef.value ?: throw UninitializedPropertyAccessException("SomeClass is not initialised yet")
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with above code is that I can call `SomeClass.initialise` again and have another instance of SomeClass in AtomicReference.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Would using AtomicReference make sense here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Atomic Reference is the way to go here

```
actual open class SomeClass private constructor(private val someProperty: SomeProperty) {
    actual companion object {
        private var someClassAtomicRef: AtomicReference<SomeClass?> = AtomicReference(null)
        fun initialize(someProperty: SomeProperty){
            val someClass = SomeClass(someProperty)
            someClassAtomicRef.compareAndSet(null, someClass.freeze())
        }
        actual fun getInstance(): SomeClass {
            return someClassAtomicRef.value ?: throw UninitializedPropertyAccessException("SomeClass is not initialised yet")
        }
    }
}
```